# Postgresql trigger not update - stack depth limit reached

Tags: postgresql, triggers, sql-update, postgresql-triggers

everyone!
i want to do a very simple trigger that sees if some conditionals are 0 they set false on the same table, buy i am doing wrong and it s not updating

```
CREATE or REPLACE FUNCTION chequeo_datos() RETURNS trigger AS $$
BEGIN
IF NEW.val_cuota = 0 or NEW.val_pat = 0 THEN
    UPDATE habitat SET status=False;
END IF;
RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER chequeo_datos AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON public.habitat
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION chequeo_datos();
```

it gives me this error : "stack depth limit reached".
could you tell me what i am doing wrong?

Comment: You have a recursion as the `UPDATE` trigger on the table does an `UPDATE` on the table which runs the `UPDATE` trigger which does an `UPDATE` and so on until the stack depth limit is reached. Read this [plpgsql trigger function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html).

Comment: you right, @AdrianKlaver. I fix that and it works, it was my first trigger

Answer (score 1):

Don't UPDATE the table, assign the new value to the record's column:

```
CREATE or REPLACE FUNCTION chequeo_datos() RETURNS trigger AS $$
BEGIN
IF NEW.val_cuota = 0 or NEW.val_pat = 0 THEN
    new.status := False;
END IF;
RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

For that to work, you need a `BEFORE` trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER chequeo_datos 
    BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON public.habitat
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION chequeo_datos()
```

Comment: thanks, that was the problem